# Memory leak after terminating web worker in Chrome + FF

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, memory-leaks, web-worker

I have a web app that needs to perform heavy JavaScript work in a background worker. I'm loading a very big file for that. Example file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/09b4d60d4c0i5dr/test.js

The problem is that loading the script to a Web Worker and then terminating that worker seems to create a massive memory leak. Chrome loses about 30MB, FF loses about 10MB. Doing this repeatedly will eventually crash the browser.

Example code:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var worker = new Worker("test.js");

// Wait until the worker is loaded, then terminate it: 
setTimeout(function() {
    worker.terminate();
}, 5000);
</script>
</html>
```

The JavaScript file itself does not perform any computation, it just defines one huge function. If you want to see its content I recommend using VIM.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

The bug has nothing to do with Emscripten. I managed to reproduce it with a very dumb function that does nothing. I updated the demo JS file.

Comment: I can’t give you any exact help, but about:memory in Firefox might give you some hints as to what’s going on. Does forcing a GC event from there reclaim the memory? It would probably also be worth submitting a bug to them with a reduced testcase ( https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi ); your usecase is probably specialised enough that you’re hitting an edge-case.

Comment: I'm using Chrome DevTools to try to track the leak, it's much friendlier than the FF about:memory. Forcing a GC doesn't help a bit... I also updated the demo and reproduced with a simple JS file. Probably this is not that of an edge-case now.

Comment: If you do create an issue with Google or Mozilla, could you please post the links here? I'd be interested in following those

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN, terminating a worker implies that "*[the] worker thread is killed immediately without an opportunity to complete its operations or clean up after itself*" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers#Terminating_a_worker), so I guess "killing" a worker isn't a reasonable option ATM if you want your web app to run without leaking too much memory...

Answer (score 0):

There's at least one [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=356205) that was opened for Chromium and they closed it as resolved in version 53.0.2785.8, but it still reproduces for me in the latest Chrome (106.0.5249.91) and Edge (105.0.1343.53)

Latest Firefox (105.0.1) doesn't seem to have the same issue. Looks like a problem in Chromium.